# Selenium Geckodriver does not open the URL

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I would like to open a page after Firefox loads:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArguments("-profile", @"C:\SomeFolder\firefox" + @"\" + profilename + @"\");
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
Thread.Sleep(2000); //I've tried without Threed.Sleep too)
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
```

Firefox opens but the URL doesn't load. I don't get any error code.

Update:
When I don't load any profile the URL loads fine. Strange...

Comment: I don't get it.... Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
You can adjust webdriver wait using driver.timeOut()